# How to call a method that is on a Form from a class?

Tags: c#, forms, class, methods

I have 2 forms on my project and like 5 classes. What I want to do is to call a method that is defined on a Form in a class, so it runs when I call it on my class. I thought about creating an instance of my Form in my class, but that would only create a "new Form" and it would be pointless. My other option is to make my form a static form, but I don't know how to do this. Thank you for your help!

EDIT

Here's the method that is defined on my Form:

```
        public void fillMatrix(char[,] currentMatrix, int rows, int columns)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                string route = GameInstance.vexedGame.imgToShow(currentMatrix[i, j]);
                DataGridVexed[j, i].Value = Bitmap.FromFile(route);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please give a specific code example of what you have and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can you not move the method to another class? Having a method on a form that you need to use in other places isn't a great idea, as instantiating a new form would use more resource than a new class, even if you choose not to show it.

Comment: The problem is that my method uses a DataGridView and fills it's cells... Here's my code:

        public void llenarMatriz(char[,] matrizActual, int filas, int columnas)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
                {
                    string ruta = InstanciaJuego.vexedGame.imagenAMostrar(matrizActual[i, j]);
                    DataGridVexed[j, i].Value = Bitmap.FromFile(ruta);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: as i understand,you need this method to populate datagridview of a form. If there is no form, there is no grid, then what do you want to achieve?

Comment: You could make the List(or whatever your datasource is) of the datagrid a static property in your form, assign it from the other class and go from there

Comment: I want to fill the DataGridView after I save the new matrix or vector, so I understand that I should save the new values of the matrix and then call this method that prints all the images I need according to my matrix... I just need to tell the method "do it now"

Comment: Code literally in another language :) Cool

Comment: I think the code doesn't necessary has to be en english but I will translate it for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Very basic example, if I've understood your original request:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public A a = null;
    public MyForm ()
    {
        A = new A(this); // pass an instance of the MyForm to the class
    }

    public void WowMethod(){
       ... something amazing ...
    }
}

public class A
{
   public MyForm associatedForm = null;

   public A( MyForm f ){
      associatedForm = f;
   }

   public void CallWowMethod()
   {
      associatedForm.WowMethod();
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok ok I think I got your idea, I will try it out, thank you very much!

Comment: Great, you helped me a lot. Just a little correction with your code: in your MyForm builder, it is:

a = new A(this); // pass an instance of the MyForm to the class

You just switched the A and the a, thanks!

Comment: fixed!( I typed it live into StackOverflow!)